# Requiring help in figuring out indent error in python code

Tags: python

I get an indentation error when trying to run the code below. I am trying to print out the URLs of a set of html pages recursively.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import *
from urlparse import urljoin
# Create a list of words to ignore
ignorewords=set(['the','of','to','and','a','in','is','it'])

def crawl(self,pages,depth=2):
for i in range(depth):
newpages=set()
for page in pages:
try:
c=urllib2.urlopen(page)
except:
print "Could not open %s" % page
continue
soup=BeautifulSoup(c.read())
self.addtoindex(page,soup)
links=soup('a')
for link in links:
if ('href' in dict(link.attrs)):
url=urljoin(page,link['href'])
if url.find("'")!=-1: continue
url=url.split('#')[0] # remove location portion
if url[0:4]=='http' and not self.isindexed(url):
newpages.add(url)
linkText=self.gettextonly(link)
self.addlinkref(page,url,linkText)
self.dbcommit()
pages=newpages
```

Comment: Where did you copy this code?

Comment: The code you have is not properly indented (Looks like a copy/paste to me), You should have a look at http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.1/ref/indentation.html to learn about proper indentation in python.

Comment: Try indenting your code bro. Saves us from a lot of headache.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're coded is totally unindented so Python will cry when you try and run it.

Remember in Python whitespace is important. Indenting with 4 spaces rather than tab saves a lot of "invisible" indentation errors.

I've down-voted as the code was pasted unformatted/unindented which means either the poster doesn't understand python (and hasn't read a basic tutorial) or pasted the code without re-indenting , which makes it impossible for anyone to answer.